# select until repeatedly

Tags: visual-mode, selection

Is there a way to repeat the "select until" operation?

For example:

```
f(a, g(b))
```

If I want to select `f(a, g(b))`.

I would like to:

- go to `f` then
- do `vf)` which will select `f(a, g(b)` and then
- do that again somehow to also select the closing parenthesis of `f`.

Comment: Try this:`:h ;`.

Comment: @Rich In this example it is at least, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
vf);
```

`f)` moves to the next parenthesis

`;` moves to the over next parenthesis

Comment: Uh, perfect. Did not know about `;`!

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: I'm quite sure you mean `vf);` and not `v f);`—that is, don't type the space.